# problem book suggetion

Tags: soft-question, representation-theory, book-recommendation

I'm taking a course on basic representation theory, where upto midsem we're supposed to learn upto $5$ th chapter of serre. Can one please suggest some book which consists of nice problems ? I've Serre, Fulton, Steinberg

Comment: There are a few that are great for physics and quantum chemistry? Does this interest you at all?  I found this subject "came alive" when I had concrete examples in mind.

Comment: No I don't like chem at all and I left phy 2 years ago

Comment: I would suggest James G., Liebeck M. "Representation and characters of groups" if you meant this kind of a representation theory. It is really very helpful and have nice examples at all.